# Typescript type safety - service doesn't return specified class object

Tags: angular, typescript

Very simple question.
Here is the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from './user';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
   private _url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

   constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) {
   }

   getUser(id: string){
      return this._httpClient.get<User>(this._url + '/' + id);
   }
}
```

getUser method returns Observable of User as I expect.
I want to get User object in component like this:
{ id: 1,  name: "a",  phone: "b", email: "c",
address: {street: "d", suite: "e", city: "f", zipcode: "g"} }

Here is the user.ts code.

```
export class Address {
   street: string;
   suite: string;
   city: string;
   zipcode: string;    
}

export class User {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   phone: string;
   email: string; 
   address = new Address();
}
```

When I call the service from component I get the whole user object from jsonplaceholder, not the User object from my user.ts code. 
My component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'newuserform',
   templateUrl: './newuser-form.component.html',
   providers: [UserService]
})
export class NewUserFormComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
   private _service: UserService, 
   private _router: Router,
   private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }

 ngOnInit(){
    let id = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this._service.getUser(id)
       .subscribe(
          user => console.log(user);
       );
 }
 }
```

Comment: What does `console.log(user)` print?

Answer (score 1):

> Typescript type safety - service doesn't return specified class object

... you have misunderstood what that means. What you are currently telling in your code, is only telling the compiler that what you expect that your http-request will return will conform to the model you have created. There is no runtime check for this. This is only to help you when you are writing code, since the compiler can tell you when you are doing something that doesn't conform to your models. It will make your debugging easier.

So you need to actually manually set the properties you want. Either by writing a function that does that for you, or like I do here, inside `map`. Also, like in other answer, I would use interfaces if there are no class specific methods.

As said, you need to set the properties you want. Here I am lazy and use `any` as the return type of the http-request, since you cannot use `User`, since that is not what you get from the http-request. You will transform the response to return a `User` though:

```ts
  getUser(id: string): Observable<User> {
    return this._httpClient.get<any>(this._url + "/" + id).pipe(
      map((user: any) => {
        return {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          phone: user.phone,
          email: user.email,
          address: {
            street: user.address.street,
            suite: user.address.suite,
            city: user.address.city,
            zipcode: user.address.zipcode
          } as Address
        } as User
      })
    );
  }
}
```

In this case you could also delete the properties that you don't want:

```ts
getUser(id: string): Observable<User> {
  return this._httpClient.get<any>(this._url + "/" + id).pipe(
    map((user: any) => {
      delete user.company;
      delete user.address.geo;
      delete user.website;
      return user as User;
    })
  );
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-blaylu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for both options.

Also read the documentation on **[classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)** and **[interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit the server response.
Try this:

Service:

```
getUser(id: string): User {
    const user = this._httpClient.get(this._url + '/' + id);
    return {
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        phone: user.phone,
        email: user.email,
        address: {
            street: user.address.street,
            suite: user.address.suite,
            city: user.address.city,
            zipcode: user.address.zipcode
        }
    };
}
```

Explain:
`const user` is the whole object returned from jsonplaceholder.
And the `return` transforms the response to your needs.

And you should define `User` and `Address` as interfaces instead of classes.

```
export interface Address {
   street: string;
   suite: string;
   city: string;
   zipcode: string;    
}

export interface User {
   id: number;
   name: string;
   phone: string;
   email: string; 
   address: Address;
}
```