# casting an observable in angular8

Tags: angular, typescript

**I am unable to cast the observable into selected fields of custom object (BookDetails: lets say Class having all variables but Title). Despite casting I am still able to access Title in the html file corresponding to the component I am calling the service in.**

I have an API returning following JSON:

```
[{"id":1,
   "Title":"The Intelligence Trap",
   "Description":"Why smart people do stupid things and how to make wiser decisions",
   "Author":"David Robson",
   "FinishDate":"2019-11-08",
   "EShop":"https://www.amazon.in"}]
```

I need to capture **all but Title**, so I cast the Observable output from http.get function inside myservice.ts into class BookDetails. I create a new component where I intend to use the service. I subscribe to the service but I can still access Title inside corresponding component's html file. Is this an expected behavior.

below is code from PullData.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { BookDetails } from "../Interfaces/book-details";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class PullDataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getDataFromService(): Observable<BookDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get<BookDetails[]>(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/Generic/newroute/"
    );
  }

  public getDummyDataFromService(): Observable<BookDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get<BookDetails[]>("/app/data/dummy.json");
  }
}
```

This is code from BookDetails.ts

```
import { Url } from "url";

export class BookDetails {
  id: number;
  Author: string;
  FinishDate: Date;
  Description: string;
  EShop: Url;
}
```

I have tried this as interface also.. to no avail. "Url" is available in node_package. **Please note that there is no Title here!**

```
**import { Url } from "url";
export class BookDetails {
  id: number;
  Author: string;
  FinishDate: Date;
  Description: string;
  EShop: Url;
}**
```

This is the component's typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { PullDataService } from "../PullData/pull-data.service";
import { BookDetails } from "../Interfaces/book-details";

@Component({
  selector: "app-roles",
  templateUrl: "./roles.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./roles.component.scss"]
})
export class RolesComponent implements OnInit {
  public books: BookDetails[];

  constructor(private pds: PullDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pds.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => (this.books = data));
  }
}
```

This is the html file for the comp

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let book of books">
    Title: {{ book.Title }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I am using Angular 8. There is no error on the page and the output is very neat Title rows for all the records in my database. Can someone please help me know what I am doing wrong here? I am TIRED! :(

Comment: You are currently just telling the compiler that what you expect as a response is of type `BookDetails`. You need to tell which properties you want from the response, this is not done "automagically".

Comment: ok. but isn't the get function's return type an Observable of an array of BookDetails? BookDetails doesn't have this variable called t

Comment: Yes, you are telling the **compiler**... "trust me, I know that what is returned from this http-request is of type `BookDetails`", the compiler trusts you. There is no runtime check for this, and what is returned from the request is all the data, unless you explicitly tell what you want, a question I answered about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662333/typescript-type-safety-service-doesnt-return-specified-class-object/58664023#58664023

Comment: Thanks AJT. I am convinced, casting isn't what I thought it is. I will need to create an object and map.

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating objects of the class `BookDetails`. You are receiving the objects and using that (You are trying to do type casting only. It doesn't change the object structure.). If you want to exclude `Title` property of the received objects, either you have to **remove the `Title` property** from objects or need to **create objects** of class `BookDetails` using a constructor.

**class**

```
export class BookDetails {
  id: number;
  Author: string;
  FinishDate: Date;
  Description: string;
  EShop: Url;

  constructor(serverObject) {
    Object.assign(this, serverObject)
  }

}
```

**component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { PullDataService } from "../PullData/pull-data.service";
import { BookDetails } from "../Interfaces/book-details";

@Component({
  selector: "app-roles",
  templateUrl: "./roles.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./roles.component.scss"]
})
export class RolesComponent implements OnInit {
  public books: BookDetails[];

  constructor(private pds: PullDataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pds.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => {
      this.books = data.map(dataObj => new BookDetails(dataObj))
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jins for helping me out here. My understanding of Obesrvable<Object> was faulty.

Comment: Ok.. now Object.assign isn't working as it should. BookDetails doesn't have Title, but Object.assign(this,obj) in the constructor isn't helping even though it should. Had to assign each variables individually.  Would be very helpful to see what could be missing.